# Sudden VueJS error: ERROR in multi vue, module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'vue' in

Tags: laravel, vue.js, npm, vuejs2, laravel-mix

Every day, I come to my office, launch my IDE (Code - OSS) and run `npm run watch`. Every day it works like a charm. But not today. Oddly enough, today running `npm run watch` fires this error:

> ERROR in multi vue
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'vue' in
> '/home/TopSecretUser/Code/Local/TopSecretProject/11.11.2020/dev'
> @ multi vue /js/vendor[0]

> ERROR in ./resources/js/app.js
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'vue' in
> '/home/me/Code/Local/TopSecretProject/11.11.2020/dev/resources/js'
> @ ./resources/js/app.js 3:13-16 4:0-22 6:0-3 85:14-17
> @ multi ./resources/js/app.js ./resources/css/app.css

My app.js starts with the following lines:

```
require("./bootstrap");

import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";

Vue.use(Vuex);

...
```

I haven't made any changes from yesterday to today, so I am totally confused. I tried some fixings but nothing worked. Does anyone have any suggestion how i can fix this? I am using vue@2.6.11.

Comment: i think the node_modules folder has some issues, try to remove it and rerun `npm i`

Comment: Thx @BoussadjraBrahim, that fiexd it! But how can this happen? Are there any understandable reasons for this issue?

Comment: probably it is an external action that affected your node_modules folder like virus or if you rename/delete/move something inside that folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could delete the `node_modules` which could be affected by an external action like deletion/moving or you mis-installed a module, then rerun :

```
npm install
```

this will fetch the dependencies in `package.json` and install them, you should always install a module by adding `--save` or `--save-dev` flag with `npm i` like `npm i some-module --save`

Answer (score 0):

guys I had this issue, after a while I found the solution , just import component as this:

```
Vue.component('Date',required('components/Date.vue'));
```

it's my pleasure to follow me on instagram: https://www.instagram.com/mahdiabedi220/